# Color the top 15% of a LaTeX background in a particular color?

Tags: latex, colors, background

I have seen documentation on how to use the [wallpaper](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/wallpaper/) package to put an image on the background, but I am looking for a simple solution to color the top 15% (or so) of a page in some color. How can I give part of the background of an output page a color with LaTeX?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you can use [PGF/TikZ](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/) to create such a [colored bar at the top of your page](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/fancy-chapter-headings/)?

Comment: Looks interesting... would require me to figure out how to get it show up on every page...

Comment: @Egon: Did you look at the code/picture properly? Make sure you do so, and also follow the link there, and you won't really need to figure out anything. It is all there!

Comment: Ah, OK. Just look at "{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]" and further?